# How To Generate wsHttpBinding Headers Dynamically In Postman

Tags: soap, postman, wshttpbinding

I've gone through Postman's documentation, the Support Center, other StackOverflow posts and Google and haven't had any luck with finding information on this. I am trying to use Postman to handle automated testing of a SOAP endpoint that I suspect uses [wsHttpBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/wshttpbinding) but haven't had any luck. Unlike another SOAP endpoint we use for which I was able to specify my headers including SOAPAction manually along with building my request by hand based on the endpoint's WSDL, this other endpoint that appears to use wsHttpBinding, based on the whole bunch of dynamically generated headers provided by SoapUI in this request I captured, leading me to believe it is using wsHttpBinding due to the extra security info:

`<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-B626B72894FCAD4E6715396529234046">
            <wsu:Created>2018-10-16T01:22:03.404Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2018-10-16T01:27:03.404Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-B626B72894FCAD4E6715396529234045">
            <wsse:Username>MyUser</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MyPassword</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    <wsa:Action soap:mustUnderstand="1">MyEndpoint</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:ReplyTo soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:MessageID soap:mustUnderstand="1">uuid:bf20cb74-39e1-4556-a110-62a4e48e71b8</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:To soap:mustUnderstand="1">MyOtherEndpoint</wsa:To>
</soap:Header>`

Does Postman have any sort of way to generate these headers?